# Signing up new AAD B2C users with various emails to LiveID automatically?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a .Net Core 2.0 Web App that connects to Azure Graph, authenticates you via OpenID and adds new local accounts to the tenant. My issue is that when I add those new users, they might or might not have their various emails registered on microsoft, LiveID. Is there maybe a way of binding their emails to microsoft in case they're not already registered? In case this is not clear enough, have an example.

In case this is not clear enough, have an example :

I add a local user with those parameters to my tenant

```
{  
   "accountEnabled":true,
   "creationType":"LocalAccount",
   "displayName":"LccotCh222602",
   "passwordProfile":{  
      "password":"Ar3g345%#3ha",
      "forceChangePasswordNextLogin":false
   },
   "signInNames":[  
      {  
         "type":"userName",
         "value":"TestAccount"
      },
      {  
         "type":"emailAddress",
         "value":"TestAccount@gmail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

And now when I try to log in to my app [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6dRu.png) (image reference) the user is not found because he hasn't registered the TestAccount@gmail.com email in Microsoft yet.

I'd like to either add that email to Microsoft automatically or find a way around it. Any tips will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new register account should work for Azure AD B2C. Here are the steps which works well for me:

1.Register the account using the REST below:

```
POST:https://graph.windows.net/adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6 
authorization: bearer {access_token}

{  
   "accountEnabled":true,
   "creationType":"LocalAccount",
   "displayName":"LccotCh222602",
   "passwordProfile":{  
      "password":"Ar3g345%#3ha",
      "forceChangePasswordNextLogin":false
   },
   "signInNames":[  
      {  
         "type":"userName",
         "value":"TestAccount"
      },
      {  
         "type":"emailAddress",
         "value":"TestAccount@gmail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

2.Login with the new register account(`TestAccount@gmail.com/Ar3g345%#3ha`)

https://login.microsoftonline.com/ADB2CFei.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_B2C_SignUpOrSignIn&client_id=420a3a24-97cf-46ca-a882-f6c047b0d845&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44316%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

[image]

And to sign-in the local account with Email, please ensure that you have enable the email sign-in like below and sign-in the app with the policy:
[image]

Comment: Ok, but how do you add those policies to your application's authentication?

Comment: Here is a [helpful link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies) for your reference to create the policy in Azure AD B2C. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi) is the link is integrate Azure AD B2C with web app.

Comment: Except that if I do that, I can't connect Azure Graph to my project using only one app.

Comment: Yes, we need to register another app instead in the Azure AD B2C blade. You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). And if you want the Azure AD B2C app supports the Azure AD Graph or any other idea and feedback about Azure AD B2C, you can submit them from [this link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

Comment: Hm, I think I might have chosen a wrong approach. All I needed was a .net core 2.0 web app that would quickly add a lot of users and had an authentication that let you log in with your local tenant account, that tenant being created in aad b2c. Am I even going the right way?

Comment: Did you mean that there is no necessary to interact with consumer account? If I understood correctly, the normal Azure AD is recommend instead of Azure AD B2C.

Comment: You'd need to log in with your local tenant account (from inside the created tenant) first to then be able to interact with the "AddUsers" action handled by Azure Graph. Outside of that there's no other interaction. It's just inside the tenant. The thing is, my application works properly now, it's just the login that doesn't connect to the policies inside the created tenant.

Comment: The permissions are passed by another application.

Comment: In this scenario, you should create the **work or school accounts** instead of **local account** if you were login without the policy. Difference between these two account, you can refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs). In-addition, the [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) is specially used to interact withe the consumer account easily.

Comment: Refer the [Create User REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser) about the difference create work or school accounts and local account.

Comment: So there's no way of using local accounts in this scenario? No way to edit the code to somehow connect to the policies?

Comment: The scenario you toke the Azure AD B2C as a normal Azure Active Directory. That why I suggest you create the work/school account instead of local account. If you still want to use local account with policy, yes. You can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs) to integrate Azure AD B2C with web app.

Comment: Hm, I looked over it and I can't really figure out how the p="policyName" is added. If you were to refer to the code sample I linked (the one with regular AD connection), could you give me some tips?

Comment: When we config the OpenIdConnect via the [StartUp class](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs#L33), it pass varies parameters include the [policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/AzureAdB2COptions.cs).

Comment: That application uses an old model of attachind OpenID - It doesn't work anymore. The way I do it is following : https://pastebin.com/raw/ypuBFibd . Using this method, I have no way of how to add the policies.